# hbase concurrent writes to one row

Tags: concurrency, hbase

I was wondering if hbase-0.90.0 has any known problems related to multiple clients writing to the same row at the same time. In my setup, there are >10 nodes writing to the same HBase table, and some times (very rarely) I'm seeing data *not* being written to the table, I log exceptions etc and I see none. One possibility is that multiple nodes are writing to the same row at once, and I was wondering if that could be causing this behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Hadoop you are using - some old version did not have durable sync and could lose data:

> HBase will lose data unless it is running on an HDFS that has a
>   durable sync implementation. Hadoop 0.20.2, Hadoop 0.20.203.0, and
>   Hadoop 0.20.204.0 DO NOT have this attribute. Currently only Hadoop
>   versions 0.20.205.x or any release in excess of this version -- this
>   includes hadoop 1.0.0 -- have a working, durable sync [6]. Sync has to
>   be explicitly enabled by setting dfs.support.append equal to true on
>   both the client side -- in hbase-site.xml -- and on the serverside in
>   hdfs-site.xml (The sync facility HBase needs is a subset of the append
>   code path).

see [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/hadoop.html) for all details